# Button not showing up in Tkinter, even w/ geometry manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm designing an app in tkinter, but there is a button that won't show up. The button is crucial to the program's operation.

```py
import tkinter as tk

global field

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)

root.geometry('368x200')

header = tk.Label(root, text = 'Header Text', pady=20)
header.config(font = ('Tahoma', 24))
header.grid(row = 0, columnspan=2)

enter_here = tk.Label(root, text = 'Question: ')
enter_here.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 50)
field = tk.Entry(root, width = 50)
field.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 50)

answer = tk.Button(root, text = 'Answer', command = answerf, width=10)
answer.grid(row=2, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Title, header text and the letters are all placeholders. I just need to figure out how to use the button. I've looked around and couldn't find any answers; most people had just forgot a geometry manager.

Comment: We don't need "a full context", we need a [mcve]. The full context is irrelevant as long as we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just wasn't sure what was the minimal reproducible example, so I put more than I actually needed to

Comment: If you can remove a line of code and the problem is still reproducible, you haven't yet created a _minimal_ example. There's lots of code in your example that can be removed. For example, is the entire `answerf` function necessary at all to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yeah, will keep that in mind next time, kinda wish I had thought of that before. Edited the code to keep it short and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful what values you are passing to various parameters of `tkinter` widgets. In above case, this is the reason why you are not able to see `button`.

Change

```
field = tk.Entry(root, width = 50)
field.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 50)
```

to

```
field = tk.Entry(root, width = 25)
field.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 30)
```

And,

```
answer = tk.Button(root, text = 'Answer', command = answerf, width=10)
answer.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

to

```
answer = tk.Button(root, text = 'Answer', command = answerf, width=10)
answer.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: No, I changed answer.grid(row=2, column=2) to answer.grid(row=1, column=2) and improve the padding. You can see yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you're forcing the window to be a size that is too small for the objects inside it.

A simple fix is to remove this line:

```
root.geometry('368x200')
```

If you insist on keeping this line, then you need to adjust the parameters of the other widgets so that they fit in the constrained space. For example, you could reduce the size of the widgets or reduce the padding.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh: like I said in the answer: reduce the size of the widgets or reduce the padding.